What is a Vector in Firestore?
I recently read that a vector is a new data type in Firestore. But what exactly is a field of type vector? I tried to add one in the Firebase Console, but no luck.

FYI I did a web search for "firestore vector" to find the answer.

From the documentation:

You can create vector values such as text embeddings from your Cloud Firestore data, and store them in Cloud Firestore documents.

This is typically used with applications that need to store vectors for use with AI/ML models.  It allows you to perform "K-nearest neighbor (KNN) vector searches".  If you don't need that, then a vector is not likely to be any more helpful than a normal array.

Do you know by chance why can I not add such a field in the Firebase console?

Does this mean text search is finally in firestore ? (fuzzy search for example)
